# How to delete HTML5 cache from UIWebView?

Tags: ios, iphone, html, browser-cache, offline-caching

I have a web page hosted with following tag to allow HTML5 cache. And the res shows a png image with some text.

```
<html manifest="offline.appcache">
```

But after deleting **ApplicationCache.db**, after deleting **cookies**, after clearing **NSURLCache**, UIWebView still shows the cached data in Airplane mode.

But how ever if I **kill** the App by double pressing the home button, it does **NOT** show the cached data.

All I want is UIWebView to not to show the cached data without out killing the app.

Comment: UIWebView is alloc/init each-time, so that I'm making sure object is not reused.